# Set-like permutations of models of set theory in an arbitrary topos

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

**Motivation:** One of the most interesting (I think) semantic properties of stratified set theories like NF(U) is that the theory is preserved under every permutation that is *set-like*, in a sense to be explained below. My objective is to see if there emerge any interesting structural ways to characterize the set-like automorphisms and the models that support them. The particular obstacle I'm encountering right now is I'm not sure I have any idea how to characterize the set-like automorphisms in categorese, or how to find a structure that works as "the object of set-like automorphisms on $X$".

**What set-like automorphisms look like set-theoretically:** Define $j$ to be $\lambda f\lambda x(f[x])$, so that $j(f)(x)$ is the image of $x$ under $f$. ($j$ and $f$ will typically live in the metatheory). We call $f$ *1-set-like* if $j(f)(x)$ is a set whenever $x$ is and $j(f)$ is also a permutation; $f$ is $n$-set-like if $j^n(f)(x)$ is a set whenever $x$ is and $j^n(f)$ is also a permutation; and it's set-like if it's $n$-set-like for all $n$.

The idea is that if you turn your model into a TST-like typed theory, an map each type $n$ onto itself by $j^n(f)$ for a set-like $f$, the result is an isomorphism of typed theories.

**The categorese I have this far:** So far in my notes I've mainly been treating models of set theories as monomorphisms $e:X\rightarrowtail PX$. I will use $\chi_e:PX\to \Omega$ to denote the classifying arrow of $e$.

Up to a point, this affords a neat way to describe set-likeness: an automorphism $\tau:X\to X$ is 1-set-like if $\chi_e \circ\exists_\tau=\chi_e$. The composite $\exists_\tau \circ e$ induces a new automorphism which, in $\mathbf{Set}$ at least, does the work of $j(\tau)$. In general, $j(\tau)$ need not be 1-set-like.

**What I can't seem to figure out** is

- how to state, internal to a topos, "$\tau$ is set-like for $e:X\rightarrowtail PX$".
- if there's a satisfying way to form a subobject of $X^X$ which "contains" the set-like functions in an appropriate  way, and on which $j$ is an endomorphism.
- whether I'm doing things the stupid way.

I tried using the Mitchell-Benabou language to import my familiarity with doing things set-theoretically, but I can't quite seem to navigate a typed language.

Congratulations and thanks to anyone who has read this far!

Comment: I may be missing something - doesn't being 1-set-like imediately imply being $n$-set-like for all $n$ (and thus the equivalency of 1-set-like and set-like), by induction?

Comment: I don't blame you for asking, it took ages to wrap my head around! The answer is "not necessarily", particularly if the set theory in question lacks separation or replacement (and NF lacks both). Take $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $e(1)=\{1\}, e(2)=\{1,2\}, e(3)=\{2\}$. Then the permutation $(1,2)$ is 1-set-like. But $j(1,2)=(1,3)$, and there is no set of which $3$ is a member.

Comment: Oh, but that does lead me to notice a detail I've left out... Editing.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine There seems to be a problem with your code.

Comment: @ZhenLin: eep! Thanks, will fix!

Comment: The internal language is the most convenient way to proceed, though there is the small subtlety of whether "for all $n$" should be understood in terms of the standard natural numbers (and thus, involve infinitary logic) or in terms of the internal natural numbers of the topos. I would not want to spell it out explicitly in category-theoretic language.

Comment: Hm, I will continue trying to get the hang of it, then... It's trying to define an inductive set with bounded quantifiers that's really tripping me.

And I would say it's more consistent with my current approach to use an NNO in the topos; I'm trying to make this aspect of NF's model theory maximally "portable".

Cheers.

Comment: @ZhenLin: But just to double check (i.e. trying not to get my hopes up), this does sound like something that can be done in the context of a topos+NNO to you? (I do try hard not to resort to Evil.)

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Why do you need an inductive set? The NNO already has an induction principle.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for a *generic* inductive set, but I am trying to find something like "the largest subset of $X^X$ closed under $j$". Which I'm having trouble with. Because types.

Comment: You surely mean "smallest". And that's easy: use the induction principle to define a sequence of subobjects of $X^X$ and then take their union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually embarassingly easy. My hangup was thinking of the "object of setlike permutations on $e:X\rightarrowtail PX$ as the closure of some subobject of $X^X$ under an operation. This is question begging since I don't know what subobject to close without already having defined "setlike".

In this case what I need is to think of sequences $i:N\to X^X$ such that $i(n)$ is 1-setlike for all $n$ and $i(S(n))$ is the kind of pullback on $i(n)$ described in my question. This is easy enough to describe in an internal language. The definition of "setlike" then becomes any $f:X\to X$ whose transpose is in the image of such a sequence.

What will be more interesting is to see if this definition of setlike, and the one arising the more traditional route in terms of isomorphisms of many-sorted models, turn out to be equivalent in a topos. (My suspicion is that the answer is "yes" and the details will be annoying, but simple.)